# Exporting a chart as image using lazy-highcharts gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lazy-high-charts

I am able to generate the charts using lazy highcharts but i want those charts to exported as images , here is my code which I am using to generate the charts

```
@fields= ReportHistory.all_history
@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
f.chart(:renderTo => 'container', :zoomType => 'x',:spacingRight=> 20)
    f.title(:text => 'Reports')
    f.xAxis(:title=>{:text => 'Days'}, :categories =>@fields.map{|x|x.Date}.last(limit=15))
    f.yAxis(:title=>{:text=> 'Jobs_count', :type =>'integer' ,:max => 5000000})
    f.series(:name =>'jobs_count', :data=> @fields.map{|x| x.jobs_count.to_i }.last(limit=15))
    f.export(:type=> 'image/jpeg')
end
```

and in my view I to show the chart I have this

```
<%= high_chart("my_id", @h) %>
```

I want to have the effect like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/type/) where I can download the chart image using  the export button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to ensure that the export module is available and loaded by your view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/highcharts/highcharts.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/highcharts/modules/exporting.js" %>
```

Second... there's nothing to do. As soon as the exporting modul is loaded, it will add the menu to export your graph.

Notes:

- You may need to adapt the paths depending on your setup.
- The `exporting.js` is part of the package you download from Highcharts.

Comment: Is there any way to do this as a background job using sidekiq to automatically download the image and save it in filesystem?

Comment: There certainly is a way, but you need to look at the exporting modules on their website. I think they mention something about a PHP script to do that.
But I think this is far from trivial...

Answer (score 1):

You can add/update the following in your `application.js`

```
//= require highcharts/highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
//= require highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display
//= require highcharts/modules/exporting
```

If you want also updated vendor assets of highcharts, you can run:

```
rake highcharts:update
```